# Clicked on warning suggestion and nullified my button id [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This code which is all dandy, and then there was a warning so I clicked it to see what it was and it changed something (not sure what, that's why I'm asking for your help) and I don't know how to revert or fix this issue.

The error: [error messege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHh0z.png)

```
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/SettingsButtonF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/SettingsButtonF"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix here, the warning was to inject a language reference, you can cntrl+shift+A (win) cmd+shift+A (mac) then type in "un-inject Language/Reference"

https://medium.com/@garrylaly/android-studio-1-4-error-aidltokentype-import-or-aidltokentype-package-expected-got-9ea2ddd85ec7#.3n9eqaq8x